# Update column status based on time

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a SharePoint 2010 application called HR Learning And Development. Basically it's an application to manage every employee trainings. Much like a college environment.
I have a SharePoint Lists named Training and Training Session. One training can have multiple sessions.
The Training Session lists have Trainer, Start-date and Status column among other things.
Employee who wants to enroll into this training would have to subscribe it.

The Training Session list should behave as follows :-
Status = New -> when a training session is just created
Status = In Progress -> when the Start-date > `Date Time.Now`
Status = Completed -> when the End-date <= `Date Time.Now`

Could you guys help me on how to solve this things.

Your help is very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a content type for the training session documents.  Then either create a workflow for that list or for that content type, your preference.  The workflow can be set to execute on both the creation and modification of a document.  You can then do the time logic you specified within a workflow and update the status accordingly.